# How to fetch which users did transaction consecutively?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, timestamp, intervals

`table_1` contains these columns: `user_id, order_id, transaction_time`

data type for `transaction_time` is `timestamp`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table_1
WHERE transaction_time > date_sub(transaction_time, interval 20 MINUTE_SECOND)
```

I want to get the people who did transaction consecutively less than 20 minutes but I lack of knowledge to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT user_id,  
       case when sum(case when  transaction_time between transaction_time and dateadd(minute,20,transaction_time) then 1 else 0 end )  > 1 
            then 'User did transaction consecutively' 
            else 'No consecutive Transaction' end
FROM table_1
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects the transaction time and the window of 20 minutes after transaction time and counts the number of transactions by that user in that window then returns where the count is greater than 1

```
select
  user_Id,
  transaction_time, 
  date_add(transaction_time, interval 20 MINUTE_SECOND)
  count(*) countofTransactions
from table_1
group by 
  user_Id,
  transaction_time, 
  date_add(transaction_time, interval 20 MINUTE_SECOND)
having count(*)>1 --having more than one transaction in the window
```